# Using C#, how do I search for images in a Windows file system like TinEye.com does on the web?

Tags: c#, windows, image-processing, ms-office, system.drawing

Hi and thanks for looking!

## Update

For the sake of clarity, a third-party .NET library is just fine.  Preferably an open-source or free one.  The solution need not be native .NET.

## Background

I am working on an enterprise web application for which the client has given us thousands of pages of content in MS Word documents that we have to parse, extract data, and send to the content database.

Within these docs are various embedded images representing a larger original image in a separate folder.

The client did not provide any paths to the original source image, so when we see content with an embedded image in the MS Word doc, we have to go through several "assets" folders and look for the corresponding image which is extraordinarily time consuming.

**We are already using [DocX](http://docx.codeplex.com) to parse the documents, so you can assume that we have a list of bitmap images to loop through that we have pulled from the document.**

## Question

Given a list of bitmaps that we just extracted from the document, how do we search a different folder containing hundreds of images, for the matching image, and then return the file path to it?

TinEye.com does this over the web.  I am wondering if, using System.Drawing or something, we can do it on a PC with C#.

Thanks!

Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hate to propose an answer to my own question, but I think I might be on to something here.  Here is heuristic/pseudo code for a C# forms app--your thoughts are appreciated:

## Part 1

1. Using System.IO, traverse the "assets" folders and get all images.
2. For each image, [Base64](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=287324) encode it.
3. Take the resulting string and place in an XML file:

> ```
> <Image>
>      <Path>C:\SomePath</Path>
>      <EncodedString>[Some Base64 String]<Encoded String>
> </Image>
> ```

Now we have an XML file containing all *original* images, in Base64 form, along with their file path.

## Part 2

1. Using [DocX](http://docx.codeplex.com), extract all images from MS Word Doc.
2. For each image, use Linq-to-Xml to search for an exact match in the XML file from Part 1.
3. If there are no exact matches, start iterating the XML file and computing the [Levenshtein distance](http://www.dotnetperls.com/levenshtein).
4. While in the `foreach` store the XML node Id (or file path) and Levenshtein Distance as a key value pair in an object.
5. Take the k/v pair with the lowest LD score and return the file path.
6. For performance, set tolerance so that the `foreach` stops if a certain original image has an acceptably low LD score when compared to the image extracted from the document.

Since this is a one-off task, I don't need instant performance.  So, I could run this tonight before leaving the office and, hopefully, come back tomorrow to a list of paths connecting the original images to the ones embedded in the docs.

## UPDATE

The heuristic above worked beautifully!  I ended up using the [Sift library](http://sift.codeplex.com) to efficiently calculate distances between Base64 strings.  Specifically, I used their FastDistance() method.  Having 100% accuracy on finding the images I need, even if the angle from which the photo was taken is slightly different.

Comment: Seems reasonable.  Note that it is probably memory-bound.  You might need to split it up into batches somehow.

Comment: Good point.  At most I have 60 images per doc, so I will just do it on a per doc basis.  Testing the theory now.  Thanks!

Comment: What happens if the same image appears in multiple documents?

Comment: Thanks Chris.  It would be okay if there is a common image in multiple docs because I am simply returning a file path.  Ultimately, I will send the local images to a CDN and then swap the local file paths out with a CDN path.  Since, at that point, I will have an association between embedded images and original image file path, I can swap that out with the respective CDN address as well.  Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisShain-Ah crud.  Hitting a System.OutOfMemory exception when I try to put the length of each Base64 string into int[length1,length2].  So, looks like you may be right about the memory issue. Still digging. . .

Comment: How about storing the Base64 version of the image on disk, and only keeping an MD5 hash of the Base64 value in memory?  A perfect match on the hash would be a trigger to go and retrieve the file from disk for comparison on the full Base64.

Comment: @ChrisShain- Thanks.  Will look into this after a barrage of meetings.  Cheers and THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in algorithm in the .NET framework for generating image similarity.  You'd need to use a third-party library or do it yourself.  Lots of image similarity algo questions on SO:

[Algorithm for finding similar images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75891/algorithm-for-finding-similar-images)

[How can I measure the similarity between two images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25977/how-can-i-measure-the-similarity-between-two-images)

[comparing images programmatically - lib or class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563033/comparing-images-programmatically-lib-or-class)

One more, for .NET: [Are there any OK image recognition libraries for .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152028/are-there-any-ok-image-recognition-libraries-for-net).  This one refers you to [AForge](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/), which seems to have the algorithm that you are after.

Comment: I'll add nother similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225210/removing-duplicate-images

Comment: Thanks to you both, but none of these links really help.  That may be the reason why the question keeps surfacing in various manifestions on SO.  I don't care whether this happens in native .NET, a library is just fine.  And, I probably can't pursue coding a library myself at the moment so all of the links above that discuss algorithmic theory aren't helpful, particularly the ones that aren't even covering .NET.  Thanks anyway though.

Comment: See my edit for another one you might be able to use more easily.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot about AForge, thank you.  I stumbled on that this past summer and the library has tons of potential for various things.  I just had an idea while pouring a cup of coffee.  I am going to try it and see if it works before jumping into AForge.  Meanwhile upvote for AForge.  Cheers!

Comment: Well, up vote in a few hours when I have a new daily quota of votes ;).

Comment: Chris, I just proposed an answer.  I would really appreciate your input if you have time.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999920/looking-for-an-image-comparison-pattern-recognition-library#6999974) to a similar question, you should look at OpenCV and VLFeat. The former has a C++ API and the latter a C API, so you would need to write your own P/Invoke wrapper or perhaps wrap them in a C++/CLI facade, which you could call from C#.

Comment: Thanks dgvid!  I will look into those.  In the meantime, I am going to propose an answer I just came up with that seems (to me) to be a bit more elegant.